# Overdue task emails suddenly stopped sending?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, designer-workflow

I have a 2013 workflow for Document Approval, and as part of the workflow, a task process is started with a SharePoint group, and sometime within the past 1-2 months, overdue task emails have stopped sending out... but no changes have been made to the workflow.

I have other workflows with task processes that send out overdue emails properly, the only difference I see between them is the one that no longer is working has an "App Step" (but after the task process).

Any settings I should check to help figure out where this is getting blocked up?

**Update**: The issue is taking place in Document Libraries, but not Lists as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've awarded the bounty to @Mohamed since he led me to find the solution.

**Document Library Tasks no longer pull due dates from the task list**

I had the workflows set with `Due Date = ""` and set the date to default to `[Today] + 2`, which had been working properly. You now need to use this calculation:

[image: Add Time to Date]

and set the output as the Due Date for the task.

Comment: Glad to hear you have solved your issue, Thank you for your appreciation :)

Answer (score 4):

**Let's investigate your issue by doing the following:**

**First,** you have said the overdue task mail was sent within the last 2 months and it stopped working now! Also, you made sure that the other workflows are sending email properly!

**That generally means** there is no issue in the pre-configured email setting for your tenant

> BTW, Unlike SharePoint OnPrem, you can't manage outgoing email
>   setting in SPO

**Second,** you have said the only difference is the `APP Step`

I don't think it causes such issue especially since it was present, and the overdue email was sending properly as you have said!

> **App step** is used to allow the workflow to be authorized with its identity as a Full Control and ignore the current user permissions.
>
> This is will ensure that the workflow will be executed successfully in
>   case the current user has no permissions. Read more at [Workflow was Suspended with Unauthorized HTTP / Elevate Workflow permissions in SharePoint](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/31/unauthorized-http-workflow-how-to-create-a-workflow-with-elevated-permissions-by-using-the-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

**Third,** you have updated your question and said The issue is taking place in Document Libraries, but not Lists!

**Actually,** the `Start Task Process` action doesn't care if it is a list or library? additionally,  there is no overdue email setting in both!

---

**Let us sum up the previous points by ignoring the imaginary causes and focus on the real causes.**

- This issue is not an email issue.
- This issue is not related to APP Step.
- This issue is not related to if it's library or list!
- This issue is related to the workflow itself by 80%.

**Let's focus on the last point,**

- Check the `last modified date` for workflow, maybe it recently modified!

  - Open SharePoint Designer > Workflow > check the modified date column for workflow.
- Whether the workflow has been modified or not, try to:

  - Check **all** `Task Process` actions, and Make sure that the `task overdue send email` is **checked** and its **recurrence** settings are set properly as you prefer.
  - Save, and Publish.

  [image]

  > Don't forget to check also the `Completion Criteria` settings, maybe the overdue condition has not been met.
- Try to create a new workflow with only `task process` action on the current document library and stop the current one to make sure that the issue is not related to the document library.
- Also, try to create a new workflow that simulates the current workflow steps on another Document library to make sure that the issue is not related to the workflow.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! 

Something I should have made clear previously is that I have versions of this workflow setup across a few subsites and they all seem to have stopped sending overdue tasks. I just setup a test workflow with only the task process to check if it works.

Comment: Great, hope this option helps you to find the root cause of your issue! I am here if you need any further support :)

Answer (score 0):

There has been recent sec update to the .net framework  that makes some of the workflows to fail:

https://www.skylinetechnologies.com/blog/skyline-blog/october_2018/sharepoint-workflow-failed-to-start

There is official guidance from MS how to resolve it:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4465015/sharepoint-workflows-stop-after-cve-2018-8421-security-update?ranMID=43674&ranEAID=je6NUbpObpQ&ranSiteID=je6NUbpObpQ-kWsEtr2UDwqhwK3zpB9cQQ&epi=je6NUbpObpQ-kWsEtr2UDwqhwK3zpB9cQQ&irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7795_1243925&tduid=(ir_559fcf05N4ea222cdbf5db2bedf431375)(7795)(1243925)(je6NUbpObpQ-kWsEtr2UDwqhwK3zpB9cQQ)()&irclickid=559fcf05N4ea222cdbf5db2bedf431375

you need to add folowing lines to your webConfig:

```
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeBinaryOperatorExpression" Authorized="True" /> 
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePrimitiveExpression" Authorized="True" /> 
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodInvokeExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeMethodReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeFieldReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodeThisReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
<authorizedType Assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" NameSpace="System.CodeDom" TypeName="CodePropertyReferenceExpression" Authorized="True" />
```

Comment: Does this apply to SP Online also, or only on-prem?

Comment: No this is on prem only, I haven't noticed your sp-online tag, sorry.